# PHP echo Javascript function not doing anything

Tags: javascript, php, function, header, echo

My website has a PHP mail code. Whenever it is ran, it is supposed to redirect (header) back to the main page and a window should pop up saying "message sent" or whatever. I implemented this using Javascript, and it works fine. This is the code in my "global.php" for reference.

```
  var msg = document.getElementById("msg");
  var opnmsg = function()
  {
    msg.classList.remove("boxoff");
    msg.classList.add("boxactive");
  }
```

Nothing impressive here. "msg" is off by default, and if opnmsg() is ran, it turns on. This works - if I type it in the inspector console, the window shows up. Also, if I write it literally anywhere else in the file, it works as well.

Unfortunately, I cannot get the window to appear only when the "mail.php" is ran. It redirects properly to the web page, but nothing shows up. Interestingly, basic functions such as alert() work fine. Here is the code snippet in question:

```
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "/en/";
    opnmsg();
  </script>';
```

Prior to using window.location, I simply used the header command, but in that case nothing would run at all, not even alert(). Additionally, the location itself is on the root, which then redirects to another page based on the browser's language, although I temporarily linked it directly just for testing (no difference). The page itself ("index.php") does have another header command which loads "global.php" (where the js code was), however, it appears that even if copying the js script to the index it doesn't work. Additionally, I've tried numerous alternatives to the opnmsg() function, including directly copying the Javascript snippet into the echo. Nothing works.

Any ideas as to what might be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: What JavaScript console show's? Any errors?

Comment: window.location will redirect, the call to opnmsg wont work as expected, why are you not using `header()`?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone As I said in the original post, header() doesn't work at all, not even for the alert() command, which works on window.location.

Comment: @EliasSoares I hadn't noticed it before (because it would clear before I could read it), but now it says "Uncaught ReferenceError: opnmsg is not defined at mail.php:3"

Comment: Probably you are placing the function usage before it's declaration

Answer (score 0):

Your code can never work. `window.location` takes you to a different website, therefore stopping any javascript the **previous** website was running. Basically nothing after `window.location` will be executed.

The easiest way to fix this is to include a `GET` parameter in the redirect and check for it on the page you're redirecting to.

If you really want javascript you could also do an `ajax request` to get the relevant data to and from the other site